# Menú responsive no funciona correctamente

Tags: android, html, css, menú, responsive

Tengo un menú responsive para una Web.
En PC/Notebook funciona correctamente tanto si el menú está a pantalla completa como si lo reduzco achicando las ventanas.
El tema es cuando pruebo el menú en el teléfono celular, el problema es que la primera opción del menú (el index) no funciona, o sea: despliego el menú correctamente, accedo a alguna de las opciones sin problemas, pero si quiero volver al index nuevamente esto no sucede. O sea toco la opción y no pasa nada, como si no tuviese vínculo alguno.
Se puede ver la web en http://www.retiradosper.com.ar/ (están disponibles algunas de las páginas).
Gracias. Gustavo.-

Comment: Hola Ghostavo. Si es tu primera vez en StackOverflow te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el recorrido. Para que alguien pueda ayudarte con tu problema es necesario que muestres las partes de tu código donde crees que está el problema.

Comment: Referente a la parte del código... pues que no lo sé! todo funciona correctamente con el ratón en una pc o notebook, pero en la pantalla del celular no lo hace.

Comment: Puedes empezar compartiendo la parte del código donde está tu menú de navegación y los miembros de la comunidad te irán orientando a partir de ahí.